# Bulk image rename in bash terminal

Tags: regex, macos, command-line, terminal, filesystems

Bonehead question, have searched and tried to use what I've found but I'm not "getting" something. LOL. My attempts have... failed.

MacOS, hundreds of images in a directory. All in a named format of AA111 (which is a product code). A = alpha char, 1 = numerical char.

So the primary image for that product is AA111.jpg. If there are related images, then they are named:

```
AA111_a.jpg
AA111_b.jpg
AA111_c.jpg
etc.
```

I'm porting over to a new shopping cart, and it wants images in format of:

```
AA111_1.jpg
AA111_2.jpg
AA111_3.jpg
etc.
```

So I need to say mv any image with name format AA111_a.jpg to AA111_1.jpg.

Back in the day I'd do this in my sleep, but I've forgotten everything I ever knew about regex.

Comment: Select the images in the Finder, right-click, and "Rename <n> items…".

Comment: I'd looked into that and I thought it wouldn't work. But... looking at it again I realize I was too narrowly focused on a "one shot" solution. Looks like with this, I can tell it to find, say "_a." and place that with "_1." Do that for A through G and I'm good! Thank you!

So I'd like to upvote this to an answer... but it looks like it's coming in as just a comment?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct command to achieve this, you may use below script:

```
cd $dir
mkdir destination
#iterate through each file contains pattern \*_\*.jpg
find . -type f -name '*_*.jpg' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
#split file name into two parts
        prefix=`echo "$line" | sed -n 's/^\(.*\)_\(.*\).jpg$/\1/p'`
        postfix=`echo "$line" | sed -n 's/^\(.*\)_\(.*\).jpg$/\2/p'`
#conver postfix(a,b,c) to ASCII
        postfix=$(expr `printf '%d' "'$postfix"` - 96)
#copy file to destination or use **mv** command
        cp $line "$to/${prefix}_${postfix}.jpg"
done
```